# jQuery | e.preventDefault not working on contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code that enforces a max character limit on a content editable div. For some reason, e.preventDefault is not working.
 This same code works if I use it on a input instead.

```
$(document).on("keyup", ".note .editable-text", function (e) {
    $element = $(e.target);
    if (e.keyCode != 8) { /* Backspace not pressed */
        if ($element.text().length > 150) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation(); //I wasn't sure if this was necessary, just added it in to see if it would help. It didn't. 

        }
    }
});
```

Like I said, this code WORKS when I use it on an input/textarea. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my asnwer please take a look,. Thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to stop user from entering text of certain length you need to use `keydown` event, because with keyup the text is already updated, and yes `e.stopPropagation();` is not needed here. Until any parent of this div is capturing keydown event.

Example Fiddle ( Given length 10 for example ):

```js
$(document).on("keydown", ".editable-text", function(e) {
  $element = $(e.target);
  if (e.keyCode != 8) { /* Backspace not pressed */
    if ($element.text().length > 10) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="editable-text" contenteditable>hello</div>
```

**Update**

updated snippet to include ctrl + a and other functionalities.

```js
function getSelectedText() {
  var text = "";
  if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
    text = window.getSelection().toString();
  } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && document.selection.type == "Text") {
    text = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  return text;
}

$(document).on("keydown", ".editable-text", function(e) {
  $element = $(e.target);
  if (!e.ctrlKey && !getSelectedText()) {
    if (e.keyCode != 8) {
      if ($element.text().length > 10) {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  }
});




$(document).on("paste", ".editable-text", function(e) {
  $element = $(e.target);
  if (e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text').length + $element.text().length > 10) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="editable-text" contenteditable>hello</div>
```

Note: Tested code on Firefox 51.0.1 (32-bit) , test it on supported browsers before using in production.

Comment: It works, except I am able to paste as the last character and exceed the limit. How can I fix this?

Comment: Ontop of that problem, how can I make it so that when the max characters is entered, I can still ctrl+a and type characters?

Comment: @Wyatt :  Thanks for the comments, I am creating a fiddle covering these things.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Thanks a million.

Comment: @Wyatt : I was able to handle paste event. https://jsfiddle.net/AjayMathur/2L576bku/3/ . I am trying to figure out to handle select all , quite a brainstorming.

Comment: Fiddle code needs to be formatted, I am still looking into getting ctrl + a work.